# GROUP BY clause giving error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables. 1st one is vacancy table

**Vacancy table:**

```
╔════════════╦═════════════╗
║ VacancyId  ║ title       ║
╠════════════╬═════════════╣
║     1      ║  Vac1       ║
║     2      ║  Vac2       ║
║     3      ║  Vac3       ║
╚════════════╩═════════════╝
```

and the 2nd one is vacancy application table

**Vacancy Application table:**

```
╔══════════════════════╦═══════════╦══════════════╦══════════════════╗
║          id          ║ VacancyId ║   source     ║ Application Date ║
╠══════════════════════╬═══════════╬══════════════╬══════════════════╣
║           1          ║     1     ║      abc     ║   2009-01-01     ║
║           2          ║     1     ║      def     ║   2009-01-02     ║
║           3          ║     2     ║      abc     ║   2010-01-02     ║
║           4          ║     3     ║      def     ║   2011-02-02     ║
║           5          ║     2     ║      abc     ║   2010-03-04     ║
║           6          ║     1     ║      def     ║   2009-04-07     ║
╚══════════════════════╩═══════════╩══════════════╩══════════════════╝
```

as you can see for a single record in the vacancy table there are multiple entry in the vacancy application table. there is another column in this table called source.  i want to count the no. of application for each vacancy by its source.

expected result

```
╔════════ ╦══════  ╦═════════════╗
║ vacancy ║ source ║ No. Of App  ║
╠════════ ╬══════  ╬═════════════╣
║   vac1  ║ ABC    ║     1       ║
║   vac1  ║ DEF    ║     2       ║
║   vac2  ║ abc    ║     2
    vac3  ║ def          1
╚════════ ╩══════  ╩═════════════╝
```

for that i have written this query

```
select v.title,  isnull(nullif(va.source,''), 'Unknown') source, COUNT(va.source) apps  from [VacancyApplication] as va inner join [Vacancy] as v on v.id= va.vacancyid     group by source
```

but its giving me an error

> Vacancy.title' is invalid in the select list because it is not
>   contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

if i exclude the vacancy title then it gives result

```
select isnull(nullif(source,''), 'Unknown') source, COUNT(source) apps 
    from [MyPeople_DataVersion2].[dbo].[VacancyApplication]
    where vacancyid in (select v.id  from [MyPeople_DataVersion2].[dbo].[Vacancy] as v where v.deleted=0 )  and deleted = 0
    group by source
```

but then i dont know the name of the vacancy... and i think it is combining the multiple vacancy source (who has the same source name) together.

can you suggest

Comment: Add `v.title` in `Group by` in your first query `..GROUP  BY v.title,source`

Comment: The problem is well described by the error message. Please read it.

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule is: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of what the aggregate is doing, iterating through rows, making unique multi col keys on the group by and applying your aggregate. What should it do with unspecified columns?

Add v.title to the group by

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following:

```
SELECT v.title,  isnull(nullif(va.source,''), 'Unknown') source, COUNT(va.source) apps
  FROM [VacancyApplication] AS va
  INNER JOIN [Vacancy] AS v on v.id= va.vacancyid
  GROUP BY v.title,  isnull(nullif(va.source,''), 'Unknown')
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add v.title to the group by

```
Select v.title,  
isnull(nullif(va.source,''), 
'Unknown') source, 
COUNT(va.source) apps  
from [VacancyApplication] as va inner join [Vacancy] as v on v.id= va.vacancyid     
group by v.title,
isnull(nullif(va.source,''), 'Unknown')
```

Answer (score 1):

just as what the error message shows you. just add the title into the `group by`

```
select v.title,  isnull(nullif(va.source,''), 'Unknown') source, COUNT(va.source) apps 
from [VacancyApplication] as va inner join [Vacancy] as v on v.id= va.vacancyid
group by source, v.title
```